# Ruby cucumber: use page object to get attribute

Tags: ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

I am looking for a way to verify link is disabled. It is a sub-menu link, I hover over to the `home menu` link, then the list of sub-menu link displays. Because of certain user role, this user cannot access to the reporting page, so I need to verify the link is disabled. The `class` attribute indicates that.

HTML:

```
  <div id="homeMenu">
    <ul>
       <li class="has-sub">
          <a class="homeButton" href="/report-web"></a>
          <ul id="homeLinks">
             <li id="oepLiId">
                  <a id="reportLinkId" class="disabledLinks" href="/report-web/openItems?subApp=OEP&rptid=15">
                  <span id="reportLinkName">Reporting Processing</span>
                </a>
             </li>
         </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

I use puts as below:

```
   link = @browser.find_element(:id, 'reportLinkId')
   puts link.displayed?
   puts link.enabled?
```

It prints:

```
   true
   true
```

The link is `displayed` and `enabled`. The only way I can think of is to check the `class` attribute to see if it is defined as `disabledLinks`.

use page object:

```
       link(:report_link, :id => 'reportLinkId')


      class_attribute = report_link_element.attribute('class')
      expect(class_attribute.eql?('disabledLinks')).to be true
```

Not use page object:

```
      class_attribute = @browser.find_element(:id, 'reportLinkId').attribute('class')
```

However, both ways, I got `class_attribute` is empty.

Environment:

```
  Ruby: 1.9.3
  Cucumber: 2.1.0
  Selenium Webdriver: 2.53.4 
  page-object: 1.2.0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In your example in HTML you have a link with `id="oepLinkId"`, but in your page object you use `:id => 'reportLinkId'`

Comment: @Evmorov Good catch. That was a typo. I updated my question. The problem still exists. Thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine for me on a simple page. Have you tried your code on a page that just has that link? What browser are you using (I tried Chrome and IE11). I was using Ruby 2.3, but seems less likely to be the issue.

Comment: @JustinKo Hi Justin, I updated my question with some additional information. The link is a sub-menu, I do hover it first, then I verify it to be disabled or not by checking its `class` attribute. I cannot make it work yet. Any thoughts please?

Comment: Are there interactions on the page that cause the "disabledLinks" class to be added/removed from the link? Please also try reproducing the problem on a simple HTML page with just this one link. That would help rule out the problem being with Selenium or a driver.

Comment: @Justin Hi Justin, thanks for your comments. I updated my question with additional information. The `disabledLinks' attribute is added when a user does not have the access. But it happens at the time the user logs in to the application. Thanks!

Comment: Is that the actual HTML the actual DOM the driver is seeing when the test runs? It just seems suspicious that it would return an empty String if there is a value. As well, is "reportLinkId" the actual ID? It seems rather generic, which might mean there are multiple on the page and you are retrieving the wrong one? What do you get if you do `puts @browser.find_elements(:id, 'reportLinkId').count`

Comment: @JustinKo Hi Justin, I tried that, it prints `1`.  There are other links, but they are not for reporting, so this id is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happened. The id value was changed during development. I updated it and it worked. Thanks to all!